# CellEditor that puts one object's field/object to the JTable model, but you select it through dropdown based on another String property of that object

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

How to write own `CellEditor` that accepts list of non-`String` objects, shows the `JComboBox` dropdown with one filed of the Object, but when selected it adds another field of the Object to the `JTable` model.

To write a custom cell editor that accepts a list of non-`String` objects and shows a `JComboBox` dropdown with one field of the object, but adds another field of the object to the `JTable` model when selected, we create a class that extends `AbstractCellEditor` and implements `TableCellEditor`. Here's an example:

```
public class MyObjectCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
    private JComboBox<Object> comboBox;
    private Object selectedObject;

    public MyObjectCellEditor(List<Object> objectList) {
        comboBox = new JComboBox<>(objectList.toArray());
        comboBox.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                setText(((MyObject)value).getFieldToShow());
                return this;
            }
        });
        comboBox.addActionListener(e -> {
            selectedObject = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            fireEditingStopped();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return selectedObject.getFieldToAdd();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        selectedObject = (MyObject)value;
        comboBox.setSelectedItem(selectedObject);
        return comboBox;
    }
}
```

In this example, the custom cell editor takes a list of non-String objects in the constructor and creates a `JComboBox` with a custom renderer that displays one field of the object. The actionPerformed method of the `JComboBox` is overridden to set the `selectedObject` field and fire an `editingStopped` event. The `getCellEditorValue` method returns the `fieldToAdd` of the `selectedObject`. The `getTableCellEditorComponent` method sets the `selectedObject` to the value of the cell being edited and sets the selected item of the `JComboBox` to the `selectedObject`.

To use this custom cell editor, we create a `JTable` and set the cell editor for a specific column:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
List<MyObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
// add objects to objectList
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new MyObjectCellEditor(objectList));
```

But how to make the list of `Object`s for `JComboBox` to be dynamically updated by the external events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JComboBox has own model too!

This will use the `MyObjectCellEditor` for the first column of the `JTable` with the list of objects passed to the constructor. When an item is selected from the dropdown, the fieldToAdd of the selected object will be added to the `JTable` model.

```
public void updateObjectList(List<Object> objectList) {
    comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(objectList.toArray()));
}
```

This method takes a new list of objects and sets it as the model for the `JComboBox`. To use this method, you can call it whenever the list of objects needs to be updated. For example:

```
MyObjectCellEditor cellEditor = new MyObjectCellEditor(objectList);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(cellEditor);

// update the objectList and the cell editor
objectList.add(new MyObject("new object", "new value"));
cellEditor.updateObjectList(objectList);
```

In this example, a new `MyObject` is added to the objectList and the updateObjectList method is called on the cell editor to update the `JComboBox` with the new list of objects. When the `JComboBox` is opened, it will show the new object in the dropdown list.